# How to generate summary report of VS 2010 DataCompare results

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, data-comparison

I am doing a SQL Server DB migration task. After the migration, I need compare the old and the new DB. I need generate a summary report (by another table or excel both are OK) to the requirement team to evaluate if the difference needs fix.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of free and paid tools available for this job. If you are ready for a paid tool, red-gate SQL Compare is a very good tool. You may search web for reviews about free tools available.